# chartjs custom y axis values, different text for each one

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, bar-chart, chart.js

I am trying to change numeric values within y axis with custom text ones. I tried using loop but it takes only the first one.

```
callback:function(value) { 
    var value = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May"];
    for(i = 0; i < value.length; i++){
        return value[i];
    }

}
```

here is [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/s5eexfs4/1/) with the sample graph

maybe case of something ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to return value from the array properly,

```
callback:function(value) { 
  var x = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"];
  return x[value | 0];                  
}
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/s5eexfs4/2/)

Comment: yes this works, but is there a way to wrap labels when text is too long. I tried with adding loop to grab it and wrap it but it does not work .

Comment: @user1751287 No I don't have idea on that. I was simply tried to fix your initial issue. Can I delete my answer now? Thanks.

Comment: @user1751287 At least this will help the future visitors to help how to set the values for y axis on the chart. So lets leave it as it is. :)